# Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException)

Tags: java, jaxb

The following error is occurring:

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.work.entity" /> 
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties"> 
        <beans:props> 
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop> 
        </beans:props> 
    </beans:property> 
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Can you share a code?

Comment: Are you using Java 9?

Comment: @SandeepKokate beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.work.entity" />
  <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
   <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
   </beans:props>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

Comment: @rghome currently using jdk 10

Comment: The above link mentions Java 9, but it should apply to anything later also.